# Error [Vue warn]: v-bind without argument expects an Object or Array value

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

Every time I toggle `show` to true I get error warning:

> Error [Vue warn]: v-bind without argument expects an Object or Array value

The Test component does not get correct value for `show` passed to it as it is always false.

My question is: how can I get rid of the warning and have VUE do what I expect it to do (toggle show and pass it to test when test emits toggle-filter)

```js
const Filter = Vue.component('Test', {
  template: `<div>
    {{show?'true':'false'}}
    <button v-on:click="toggleFilter">toggle</button>
  </div>`,
  props: ['show'],
  methods: {
    toggleFilter(e) {
      this.$emit('toggle-filter', e);
    },
  },
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  //components: {Filter},
  data: {
    show: false,
  },
  methods: {
    toggleFilter() {
      this.show = !this.show;
      console.log('show:',this.show);
    },
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <Test v-bind.show="show" v-on:toggle-filter="toggleFilter"></Test>
    {{show?'true':'false'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should have **v-bind:show** instead of **v-bind.show**.

Comment: That's it, thank you. Do you know if there are any dev tools/plugins for vscode that allow me to create vue code without having to guess what the syntax is and letting it spit out unhelpful errors during runtime?

Comment: I installed that but doesn't do anything for `.html` files (it doesn't know they are templates), my vue files look like `<template src="./template.html"></template>`

Comment: Thank you! This should be accepted as the answer! :)